# Angular 2 - How to access directives from Component

Tags: typescript, angular

I attached a dialog component as a directives in order to show it on the main component page when I click on the button on the main page (which link to the main component). This is how I did it

**In the template**

```
<button id="goToTasksCases" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" (click)="doShowStartNewCase($event)">START A NEW CASE</button>
<modal-new-case></modal-new-case>
```

**In the component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'case-index'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'client/app/case/case.index.html',
    directives : [ModalNewCaseComponent]
})
export class CaseIndexComponent {
    doShowStartNewCase(event: any) {
        // how can I access the ModalNewCaseComponent
    }    
}
```

However, i need to set some values for the child component (`ModalNewCaseComponent`) after some callback from Rest service. How can I achieve that with the current setup ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can query the view children by:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'case-index',
    templateUrl: 'client/app/case/case.index.html',
    directives : [ModalNewCaseComponent]
})
export class CaseIndexComponent {
    @ViewChild(ModalNewCaseComponent)
    modal: ModalNewCaseComponent;

    afterViewInit() {
        // this.modal will have value
    }

    doShowStartNewCase(event: any) {
        // how can I access the ModalNewCaseComponent
    }    
}
```

You can find more about [ViewChildren and ContentChildren here](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/).

Comment: jesus !! I searched google for the last hour and didn't find any thing close to this (mostly come up with viewManager, element....). You are a life saver !!!!!

Comment: It'll be explained further here https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/switching-angular-2  :-)